# Build Web GUI with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, jakarta-ee, struts2, web

does exist a plugin for eclipse that allows me to build Web GUI (not Swing Gui) using a drag'n'drop tool (like Visual Studio .NET)?
I would like build forms with input text field, checkboxes, etc... without write the html code.
Does exist this same plugin for Struts 2?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

All plugins that provide such an opportunity is very uncomfortable at work.
From personal experience I can say that it is easier to write xml than drag-drop components in Eclipse.
BTW you can try [Oracle JDeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/overview/index.html). JDeveloper have UI designer for JSP pages.
And another option: http://www.myeclipseide.com/module-htmlpages-display-pid-12.html